# For Register customer, After adding the item to cart, when clicked on the edit product, customer header display signin

Tags: customer, magento2.4.3.p1, headerlink

For Register customer, After adding the item to cart, when clicked on the edit product in Mini-cart, customer header display signin. ever had anybody faced this kind of error. Please help me if anyone know the solution.

Comment: Can you share some screen shots since it's not clear to everyone what the actual issue is?

Comment: Question is not very clear but it seems you are saying that customer section reload is not working as expected. I suggest you to provide more details about the issue and also what is your magento version?
Also please check this thread it might help https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29081

Comment: you can set the header as cacheable="false" and testing your issues may be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a session problem.

The mini cart client side js is not detecting that the customer is logged in and is prompting for a login even though the customer is logged in.

To troubleshoot this further :

- start a new incognito / private window and browse to your shop
- log in as a customer
- add a product to the cart
- use the mini cart navigation links to go to the cart / checkout

If you are prompted for a login you need to troubleshoot your session configuration in Magento further and check that your session cookies are saved correctly in your browser without errors.